# how to appear the JLabel and the JTextField appear as vertical in the center?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

my question is why is label and textfield appear cramped and is horizontal? i tried changing the x and y but it is still cramped and i cannot move it as if it is grouped together.

```
  JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
  panel_2.setBounds(10, 162, 237, 108);
  panel_2.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
  friedchiken.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
   //create another panel
  JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
  panel3.setBounds(248, 162, 250, 108);
  panel3.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
  friedchiken.getContentPane().add(panel3);
  
  //create quantity textfield here
  JLabel quantity1 = new JLabel("quantity :");
  JTextField quantity = new JTextField();
  quantity1.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 30);
  quantity.setBounds(150, 150, 150, 30);
 panel_2.add(quantity1);
 panel3.add(quantity);
 
  
//create combobox here
  JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
  comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Please choose one:", "Mastercard/Visa","Cash" , "eWallet" , "CryptoCurrency"}));
  comboBox.setBounds(150, 300, 150, 30);
  panel3.add(comboBox);
  
  
 //create another textfield for credit card number
  JLabel creditcard = new JLabel("credit card number:");
  JTextField numbercc = new JTextField();
  creditcard.setBounds(50, 300, 150, 30);
  numbercc.setLocation(150,300);
  numbercc.setBounds(150, 300, 150, 30);
  panel_2.add(creditcard);
  panel3.add(numbercc , BorderLayout.CENTER);
  panel_2.setVisible(true);
  panel3.setVisible(true);
```

here is the picture i have with me when i run the program
[image: it is cramped side to side]

Comment: Hi, please add a draft of your expected layout and take some time to create a [mimimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will help us to answer to your question.

Comment: The setBounds(...) statements do nothing. Get rid of them. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The default layout manager for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout` which will display components horizontally and then wrap to a new row when the row is full. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. You can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: When you create a JTextField you use something like `new JTextField(10)`. The will allow the text field to determine its preferred size to display 10 "W" characters. You didn't specify the columns which is why it is displayed so small.